# Website & App_Code not working correctly (#C)

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, visual-studio-2012, app-code

I am simply trying to call methods in a website from the app_code folder, but I did not make the project in Visual Studio, I used Azure.

All the aspx files are in the /site/wwwroot folder while my App_Code folder is outside of everything.

I have tried using namespace calling and where others have just said change compile settings in the class properties but that options do not appear under the class properties. (I think its because I created the project using Azure, I am not too sure)

Here is what my code looks like right.

#### Scores.aspx.cs

```
using Tennis;

public partial class site_wwwroot_Scores : System.Web.UI.Page 
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        private List<Player> players = null;
        players = PlayerDB.GetPlayers();
        FillListBox();
    }

    protected void FillListBox()
    {
        //foreach (Player p in players)
        //{
        //    lstBxPlayers.Items.Add(p.GetDisplayText());
        //}
    }

}
```

#### PlayerDB.cs (located inside the App_Code folder)

```
namespace Tennis 
{
    public class PlayerDB
    {

        public PlayerDB()
        {
        }

        public static List<Player> GetPlayers()
        {
            // create the list
            List<Player> players = new List<Player>();

            // create the XmlReaderSettings object
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
            settings.IgnoreComments = true;

            // create the XmlReader object
            string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/site/wwwroot/players.xml");
            XmlReader xmlIn = XmlReader.Create(path, settings);

            // read past all nodes to the first Player node
            xmlIn.ReadToDescendant("Player");

            // create one Player object for each Player node
            do
            {
                Player p = new Player();
                xmlIn.ReadStartElement("Player");
                p.PlayerNumber = xmlIn.ReadElementContentAsString();
                p.PlayerTotalSetScore = xmlIn.ReadElementContentAsString();
                p.PlayerTotalWin = xmlIn.ReadElementContentAsString();
                players.Add(p);
            }
            while (xmlIn.ReadToNextSibling("Player"));

            // close the XmlReader object
            xmlIn.Close();

            return players;
        }
    }
}
```

Visual Studio shows no errors or anything, but whenever I try to browse my website, a run time error occurs.

Comment: Try using remote debugging to catch the issue. You can use remote debugging to attach to your web app and debug it (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/).

Comment: I see no web config file whenever I look at the sever explorer in VS, I only see a web config file whenever I open the website via VS

Comment: "A runtime error occurs" you need to tell us what that error is.

Comment: It just says Server Error in '/' Application because I am unable to enable remote debugging

Comment: The error message (it's called a Yellow Screen of Death or YSOD) explains how to enable it so that you can see that actual error message. Follow those directions. You have to modify the web.config.

Comment: Hi @KorwynnWagstaff have you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

For the webserver in azure (IIS) the **/site/wwwroot** folder is the website root Path. The folder that contains all the application code, any other thing outside that folder is taken as no application code.

Take a look a to the full folder structure (typical) for an azure web app

[image]

Because of that your App_Code folder is not Compiled/processed at runtime.

You should move App_Code folder into **/site/wwwroot/**

But, my advice -strong advice- is that you construct your whole solution from Visual Studio, this could help you to avoid this kind of errors and for sure a lot of other mistakes that can leave you in the hell.